# Make terminal script which runs a terminal command

Tags: macos, executable

I am on a mac and want to make a batch script which runs a terminal commmand on double click.

I have found several of tutorials but all of them shows how to echo something?

What I want is to run this when I double click the script:

```
My-MacBook-Pro:platform-tools myname$ ./adb logcat -s Unity
```

I have saved this into a file called: mytest.command

When doubleclicking this I get this:

> Last login: Wed Dec 17 09:26:04 on ttys001 My-MacBook-Pro:~ myname$
>   /Users/myname/Documents/mytest.command ; exit;
>   /Users/myname/Documents/mytest.command: line 1:
>   My-MacBook-Pro:platform-tools: command not found logout

How can I accomplish this?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to know where you have installed `adb`. If you know it is in `/usr/local/bin` for example, then that is fine. However, if you don't know where it is installed, type

```
which adb
```

or

```
whereis adb
```

and it will tell you. Now, remove the word `adb` from the answer you get, so you just have the path to the directory (folder) where `adb` lives. Now you have the path, you can write your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:XXXXXXXX
adb logcat -s Unity
```

where XXXXXXX is the path to the folder where `adb` lives.

Comment: Any luck, or are you still stuck?